# Problem with understanding SRP

Tags: design, design-patterns, c++, single-responsibility

I have a hard time understanding when the Single Responsibility Principle is correctly used. Consider the following code:

```
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void CTCPClient::Try_Send_Data(const char *Outgoing_Message)
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
    Reset_Return_Value();
    Copy_Data_Into_Buffer(Outgoing_Message);

    try
    {
        if((strcmp(Outgoing_Message, "") != 0))
        {
            Send_Data();
            Keep_Alive_Counter = 0; // reset as a button has been pressed
        }

        if(Return_Value <  0)
        {
            throw SEND_DATA_TCP_ERROR;
        }
    }

    catch(EError_ID)
    {
        Error_Message = strerror(errno);
        LOG_WARNING(__SOURCE__ << Error_Message);
    }
}
```

If I would read this method for the first time, I would, as the name sugest, expect a try and catch statement. But before that I´m calling two additional methods (Reset_Return_Value(), Copy_Data_Into_Buffer()). Is the SRP already violated here?

Further in the method I'm setting "Keep_Alive_Counter = 0;". In my opinion, at least at this point the SRP has been violated in addition to the fact, that if I were to be someone who didn't write the code, would simply not expect this line to be there. The problem I have here is: If I do this in an explicit method, it will be a one line method, something I encounter more often, as I try to consinder the SRP. These methods still look weird to me and I haven't found an answer to when they are considered good pratice. Always? In some cases? Never?

This is my own code so feel free to criticize, as long as it is constructive.

EDIT: Keep_Alive_Counter and Return_Value are class attributes, which are changed/used by other methods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When considering whether or not a function or a method violates the SRP, you should look not at the implementation of the method but at what it's supposed/promises to do. Consider the following two functions:

```
void printTime() {
    print(getTime());
    invade(POLAND);
}

void printTimeAndInvadePoland() {
    print(getTime());
    invade(POLAND);
}
```

Only the second function violates the SRP. `printTimeAndInvadePoland` has two responsibilities - to print the time and to invade Poland. `printTime` does not violate the SRP, as it has only one responsibility - to print the time. It has a different problem - unwanted [side-effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)). You just want to print the time and suddenly you started a world war. `printTimeAndInvadePoland` does not have unwanted side-effects because it's supposed to invade Poland - that side-effect is part of it's responsibility.

Let's look at your `Try_Send_Data`. It has one responsibility - to send the data. You are worried about the calls to `Reset_Return_Value` and `Copy_Data_Into_Buffer` and about resetting `Keep_Alive_Counter`. Does any of them violate the SRP? No - because they don't change the fact that `Try_Send_Data`'s only responsibility is to send the data. So the question is - do they make the method deviate from it's responsibility?

- `Reset_Return_Value();` - it looks like it refers to the return value of some lower level data transmission function that you call from `Send_Data`, and `Send_Data` is setting. This is not a violation of the SRP, but it's still a bad practice: `Send_Data` should either return that value or throw an exception if it indicates an error. Even if you keep `Send_Data` as is, if it guarantees to always set `Return_Value` you can move the `if(Return_Value <  0)` check to only happen when `Send_Data` is called, and then you won't have to reset it.
- `Copy_Data_Into_Buffer(Outgoing_Message);` - I see no problem here. While I don't know if it copies the data **to** or **from** `Outgoing_Message`, this copy seems like a necessary task for sending the data, which supports `Try_Send_Data` one responsibility.
- `Keep_Alive_Counter = 0;` - updating the keep-alive information is part of the data sending process, so there are no weird side-effects here, but I don't think this line belongs here. If you update the keep-alive info every time you send data(makes sense), it should be done inside `Send_Data`. If, like the comment indicates, you only update it when a button is pressed(WTF?), it should be done in the button press event handler.

Of course, if `Send_Data` is not yours, and `Try_Send_Data` is a convenience wrapper around `Send_Data`'s awkward API, this may be acceptable - though you might want to rename `Try_Send_Data`, because right now it's name indicates it's just a variation of `Send_Data` that does not throw, when it clearly does more. If you can change `Send_Data`, consider moving some of `Try_Send_Data`'s functionality(like copying the data to the buffer, resetting the keep alive counter, and throwing in case of bad return value) to `Send_Data`.

Comment: Ridiculous good explanation. Good in terms of easy to understand. Thank you :-) On a sidenote, the "invade(POLAND)" example really made me smile.

Comment: It didn't make the Polish smile...

Comment: Suddenly I'm not sure anymore, if the "invade(POLAND)" thing was meant as a joke. If my smiling to that insulted you, I apologize.

Comment: Don't worry, it was a joke. I mean, it was in my pseudocode. It wasn't a joke when Hitler did it.

Comment: Alright then :-)

Comment: @IdanArye Sorry but you are 100% wrong. What a function promises to do, doesn't justify mixed responsibilities.

Comment: @53777A What a function promises to do **defines** it's responsibilities. `printTime` does not have mixed responsibilities because invading Poland *is not* a responsibility of it - it's just something the function does as a side-effect, which is a whole different problem.

Comment: @IdanArye Please read my answer and some of the original texts regarding SRP. There is a quote there from Uncle Bob himself :)

Comment: @53777A I accept your criticism. I neglected to read the definition and answered from my own knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is very simple.

> Martin [who coind the word] defines a responsibility as a reason to change, and concludes that a class or module should have one, and only one, reason to change. ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle))

That means if your function, regardless of their name or what they promise to do, has more than one reason to change, then it violates the SRP.

As an example, a function that searchs for a user record in the database and returns the result, doesn't violate the SRP, even though it may have a long and complicated logic inside.

On the other hand, a function that would look up for the user and would return the user record or create one if couldn't find any matching records, violates SRP because the second function has two reasons for change 1) when the look up logic changes 2) when the record creation logic changes.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is quite weird, because you are checking variables not defined in that method. I don't see whole class, but I can only assume that they are somehow changed in other methods. So, even that you tried to make it nice, you managed to create something that looks like spaghetti code.

To answer your question: yes that is SRP, but done in a very bad way.

I can recommend you to read ["Clean Code"](https://www.amazon.de/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882), and redo your class.

Comment: I have eddited my question. The varibales you speak of are in fact class attributes, like you assumed. Maybe I'm wrong here, but isn't the whole reason of attributes, that you can use them in different methods? I've already read clean code. Thats where my questions came from. Thanks anyway, it still good to see, how someone who didn't write the code reacts to it.

Comment: @YokeM and what are those functions (like Send_Data()? Private member functions?

Answer (score 0):

I think SRP is not correctly used in here. Reset_Return_Value() and Copy_Data_Into_Buffer() can be used separately. You can set a variable to hold your values and use those two methods separately. In that way, if the mechanism of Reset_Return_Value() or Copy_Data_Into_Buffer() changes, it won't affect your code. Something like the following:

```
Reset_Return_Value();
Copy_Data_Into_Buffer(Outgoing_Message);
Try_Send_Data(Outgoing_Message);
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------  -------------------------
void CTCPClient::Try_Send_Data(const char *Outgoing_Message)
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
  try
   {
    if((strcmp(Outgoing_Message, "") != 0))
    {
        Send_Data();
        Keep_Alive_Counter = 0; // reset as a button has been pressed
    }

    if(Return_Value <  0)
    {
        throw SEND_DATA_TCP_ERROR;
    }
}
catch(EError_ID)
{
    Error_Message = strerror(errno);
    LOG_WARNING(__SOURCE__ << Error_Message);
 }
}
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void CTCPClient::Reset_Return_Value()
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
           //...code to reset the return value
}
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void CTCPClient::Copy_Data_Into_Buffer(const char *Outgoing_Message){
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
              //.........code to copy the data into buffer
}
```

Comment: If the mechanism of `Reset_Return_Value` or `Copy_Data_Into_Buffer` changes, wouldn't you **want** code that needs to reset the return value or to copy data into a buffer to use the new, fixed/improved mechanism?

Comment: I have edited my answer to explain my point of view. Please have a look at it and let me know if I'm making a mistake.

Comment: This makes things worse. If `Reset_Return_Value` and `Copy_Data_Into_Buffer` are needed for the rest of `Try_Send_Data` to operate properly, why would you change it so one could run without them? With your version, one could easily neglect to reset `Return_Value`, making `if(Return_Value <  0)` possibly use an old value. Or they can send different `Outgoing_Message` to `Copy_Data_Into_Buffer` and to `Outgoing_Message`, making `if((strcmp(Outgoing_Message, "") != 0))` validate a different message then the one that will be sent.